# Possibility of modifying the Overview tab in Pandas Profiling

Tags: python, pandas-profiling

I wish to remove the "Warnings" and "Reproduction" menu options/tabs which are present under the "Overview" tab in the pandas-profiling HTML report.

[image: Sample Profile Image]

We want to integrate this in our application to show a basic understanding of the datasets. We would want to remove the warnings which is our requirement.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible as per the package documentation.

You can control the number of warnings you can display though.